# Use output from awk program in `END` section

Tags: awk

I want to interpolate some values into a JSON template file: a count of file paths, and a list of paths themselves. I'm struggling to use the output of the main body of my awk script in the `END` section.

The output should look a bit like this:

```
{
 "quantity": 3,
 "files": [
    "example_folder/file1.txt",
    "example_folder/file2.txt",
    "/file3.txt"
  ]
}
```

I have an awk script that, given a list of files in an `example_input.txt` file, extracts a comma-separated list of the paths I'm interested in and outputs them to `paths.txt`. I'm able to determine the quantity of files I'm interested in beforehand, so I pass it to the script as a variable (e.g. `awk -v line_count="$FOO"`).

I thought that this should be possible with `getline`, as follows:

```
{
    [...] # rules as described
    print "\"" path "\"" > "paths.txt"
}
END {
    getline < "body.json.tpl"
    body = $0

    getline < "paths.txt"
    paths = $0

    sub(/paths_replace_me/, paths, body)
    sub(/quantity_replace_me/, line_count, body)

    print body > "body.json"
}
```

But this doesn't work; `paths.txt` is never read in by `getline`, and so while `quantity_replace_me` is replaced as desired, I end up with `body.json.tpl` interpolated into the middle of itself, a bit of a mess. It looks like this:

```
{
"quantity": 3,
"files": [ {
    "quantity": quantity_replace_me,
    "files": [
         files_replace_me
     ]
 } ]
}
```

In the course of my debugging, I've tried printing out `body` and `paths` to see what's going on. `paths` is never set to the contents of `paths.txt`.

I don't understand why?

In addition, I'm not sure what the correct way to do this is. I've tried splitting my `END` section off to a separate script, and this produces the desired output - but it seems like it should be possible, by redirecting output somehow, to do this all in one script. Can anyone please assist?

Comment: When doing a `close("paths.txt")` just before the `getline < "paths.txt"` it should work, because reading start at the beginning of the file. But there should be a smarter solution to this.

Comment: @Luuk thanks so much for explaining this, and for the solution you posted below!

You've answered the first question I posed directly, but I wanted to get more info on that if possible please. I wouldn't have known to `close` the file, and none of the tutorials I read alluded to this function. Can you point me to any resources that would help me gain a deeper understand of why this was necessary?

Comment: Most of the knowledge I have is from doing stuff with (g)awk. (and from programming in general). Reading the man-page gives some tips, but using gawk and, when needed trying to find the solution in the [man-page](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) or online. I am still learning, and there are others (like [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton)) who know way more about (g)awk than  do.... 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a file with filenames like:

```
example_folder/file1.txt
example_folder/file2.txt
/file3.txt
```

Then you could create a script (i.e. `script.awk`) like:

```
{ a[i++]=$0 }
END{
        print "{ \"quantity\":" length(a) ", \"files\": [ "
        for(i=0; i<length(a); i++){
                x=(i==length(a)-1?"] }":",")
                print "\"" a[i] "\"" x;
        }
}
```

output of: `gawk -f script.awk files.txt`:

```
{ "quantity":3, "files": [
"example_folder/file1.txt",
"example_folder/file2.txt",
"/file3.txt"] }
```

Above should be a valid json-file.

Comment: Much obliged for this as mentioned above. To contextualise your solution with the 2nd question in my original post:

The smartest way to use the output from an awk script in the `END` section is to collect the lines into an array as they're being processed, and then iterate through the array in `END`. Is that a fair characterisation?